# Additive inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Hey so I got a question about Vector spaces

> Let $V=(8,\infty)$. For $u,v$ in $V$ and $a$ in $\mathbb R$ define vector addition by $u\boxplus v:= uv-8(u+v)+72$ and scalar multiplication by $a\boxdot u :=(u-8)^a +8$. It can be shown that $(V,\boxplus,\boxdot)$ is a vector space over the scalar field $\mathbb R$. Find the additive inverse of 16.

So what I did was find the zero vector which is 9, and set u to 16, but that was the incorrect answer. So I'm confused as to how you find the additive inverse.

Thanks!

Comment: $16\boxplus x = 9 \Leftrightarrow 16x - 128 - 8x + 72 = 9 \Leftrightarrow 8x = 65 \Leftrightarrow x = 1 + \dfrac1{8}$. You can also put $a=-1$ in the definition of scalar multiplication and obtain the same result.

Comment: Ah, I think you mean 8+ 1/8 but yes, thank you!

Comment: @FPE You could make that an answer... :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ The vector space arises by [transport of structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190326/242) from the vector space $\,(0,\infty)\,$ to $\,(8,\infty)\,$ along the shift-bijection $\,s(v)= v+8,\,$ with inverse $\,t(v) = v-8.\,$ The former vector space has the simpler vector operations given by $\ a u \oplus b v = u^a v^b.\,$  Transporting is defined so that the the maps $\,s,t\,$ are vector space isomorphisms, e.g. $\ t(u\boxplus v) = t(u)\oplus t(b)\,$ so the transported addition is

$$ u\boxplus v\, =\, t^{-1}(t(u)\oplus t(v))\, =\, (u\!-\!8)(v\!-\!8)+8\, =\, uv -8(u\!+\!v)+ 72$$

Thus you can compute inverses straightforwardly by first  performing the simpler inverse computation  in the space $\,(0,\infty)\,$ then shift-transporting the solution to $\,(8,\infty),\,$ as above.

**Remark** $\ $ Although this problem is so simple that one could skip the conceptual transportation viewpoint and do the computation by brute-force, this would be much more difficult to do in more complex examples. For example, in Gauss's *Disq. Arith.* the proof of associativity of composition of binary quadratic forms comprises many pages of unilluminating abstruse calculations, whereas nowadays this [can be done by  simply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/410194/242) by transporting the class group structure from ideals to primitive binary quadratic forms.