# Show that * is associative

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations, associativity

Could you show me how to prove the following to be associative? Please take me through the process step by step.

$$a*b=a+b+2ab$$

Where $*$ is a binary operation and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

I have got this far:

$$(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$$
So $$(a+b+2ab)*c$$
And $$a*(b+c+2bc)$$

I am not sure what the next step would be.

Many thanks,
Conor

Comment: Do you know what "associative" means?

Comment: Yes. It is a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c

Comment: Ok. Can you write down the right- and left-hand side and compare?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: At the place where you are stuck, $a*(b+c+2bc)$, the expression $(b+c+2bc)$ is one unit. Let's temporarily rename that unit $B$. Then $a*(b+c+2bc)=a*B = (a+B+2aB)$. And now you re-substitute $B=(b+c+2bc)$ to get $(a+(b+c+2bc+)+2a(b+c+2bc)$ and the rest is algebra. Recognizing these "units" , and correctly applying this kind of substitution, is a basic and important mathematical skill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation $*$ will be associative iff
$$a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$$

So let's compute both sides of equation:

$$a*(b*c)=a*(b+c+2bc)=a+b+c+2bc+2ab+2ac+4abc$$

$$(a*b)*c=(a+b+2ab)*c=a+b+2ab+c+2ac+2bc+4abc$$

Since they are the same, the operation is associative.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain the last step were you merge the a and then the c with what is in the brackets?

Comment: @ConorMacBride: just set $x=(a+b+2ab)$ then  $x*c=x+c+2xc$ then put
$x$ in the last equation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\mathbb R \setminus \{-1/2\}$ and consider the bijection $f\colon X \to \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ given by $f(x)=1+2x$. Then
$$
a*b=a+b+2ab=(2a+2b+4ab)/2=(1+2a+2b+4ab-1)/2\\=f^{-1}((1+2a)(1+2b))=f^{-1}(f(a)\cdot f(b))
$$

So, the operation $a*b$ is the *pullback* of ordinary multiplication via $f$. By construction, all properties of $a*b$ are reflection of the properties of ordinary multiplication, and $f$ is an isomorphism of groups.

In particular,  $a*b$ is associative, has $0=f^{-1}(1)$ as neutral element, and $f^{-1}(1/f(a))=a/(1+2a)$ as the inverse of $a$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/373743/589 and http://math.stackexchange.com/a/513054/589.

Comment: This is a special case of [transport of structure.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20transport%20structure)

Comment: @BillDubuque, that term is new to me, it makes sense, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes that name is only used in less trivial cases, e.g. in Gauss's *Disq. Arith.* the proof of associativity of composition of binary quadratic forms comprises many pages of unilluminating abstruse calculations, whereas nowadays this [can be done simply](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/410194/242) by transporting the class group structure from ideals to primitive binary quadratic forms. And +1 for the general viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
a * b = a + b + 2 a b
$$

Then

$$
a * (b * c) = a * \big( b + c + 2 b c \big) = a + \big( b + c + 2 b c \big) + 2 a \big( b + c + 2 b c \big)\\
= a + b + c + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc + 4abc
$$

and

$$
(a * b) * c = \big( a + b + 2 a b \big) * c = \big( a + b + 2 a b \big) + c + 2 \big( a + b + 2 a b \big) c\\
= a + b + c + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc + 4abc
$$

so

$$
a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c
$$

Answer (score 1):

A quicker way is to remark that
$$a*(b*c)=a*(b+c+2bc)=a+b+c+2ab+2ac+2bc+4abc$$
is invariant under permutation of $a,b,c$ and $*$ is commutative (i.e. $a*b=b*a$). Therefore,
$$a*(b*c)=c*(a*b)=(a*b)*c$$
i.e. $*$ is associative.

Answer (score 0):

The operation $*$ will be associative if this condition is true
$$a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$$

So let's compute both sides of this equation:

$$f1=a*(b*c)=a*(b+c+2bc)$$

$$f1=a*(b+c+2bc)=a+(b+c+2bc)+2a(b+c+2bc)$$

$$f1=a+(b+c+2bc)+2a(b+c+2bc)=a+b+c+2bc+2ab+2ac+4abc$$

$$f2=(a*b)*c=(a+b+2ab)*c$$

$$f2=(a+b+2ab)*c=(a+b+2ab)+c+2c(a+b+2ab)$$

$$f2=(a+b+2ab)+c+2c(a+b+2ab)=a+b+c+2bc+2ab+2ac+4abc$$

As you can see $f1=f2$

So they are the same and the operation is associative.